# Guard does not spot file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, guard, inotify

I've recently updated my gems with `bundle update` and all of the sudden Guard is now failing to pick up file changes on watch. 
I need that back working. Here's some info. If any more needed, ask right away.

The Gemfile setup for Guard and Rspec:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "guard-rails"
  gem "guard-livereload"
  gem "rack-livereload"
end
```

The Gemfile.lock part for Guard

```
guard (2.2.4)
  formatador (>= 0.2.4)
  listen (~> 2.1)
  lumberjack (~> 1.0)
  pry (>= 0.9.12)
  thor (>= 0.18.1)
guard-livereload (2.0.0)
  em-websocket (~> 0.5)
  guard (~> 2.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.8)
guard-rails (0.4.7)
  guard (>= 0.2.2)
guard-rspec (4.0.4)
  guard (>= 2.1.1)
  rspec (~> 2.14)
```

[The Guardfile](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/7547557) (too big to paste here).

Once again. I run `bundle exec guard` in the terminal, it boots up perfectly. Then I change a file (a model for example) in my editor (RubyMine or Gedit), and Guard does not pick that change to run the specs.

Comment: you are using rb-inotify. Are you on a Linux box or a Mac?
EDIT: Nevermind you mentioning Gedit, so linux and rb-inotify is fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Arch Linux. I could not figure out the root cause, but running guard with the -p option solved the problem for me.